# Logic puzzle 4x4 grid

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I have been trying to get to solution for some time now, and it starts irritating me. Anyone?
[image]

Comment: All the columns sum to 14, so the answer could be 4.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl I came to the same conclusion but it seems strange that the rows don't have any particular coherence

Comment: Thought the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> C

Because

> the columns all add up to 14.